# Checking textbox lengths in PHP

Tags: php

```
if ($username  != '')
{
if($password != $password1)
{
echo 'Password does not match<br />';
    }
else if ($username > 14)
{
echo 'username too long';
}
else if ($username < 5)
{
echo 'username too short';
}
else if($password < 5 && $password1 < 5)
{
echo 'Your password or username is too short, minimum of 5 characters<br />';
}
    else{
```

I tried this several times but it says my username is too short even when it has 9 characters in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the length of a string in PHP use [`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php).

For example:

```
if (strlen($username) > 14)
{
  echo 'username too long';
}
```

Note: to check whether a variable is set in PHP, use [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) instead of `!= ''`, it is much more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strlen()`

```
if(strlen($username) < 5) {
   // too short 
}
```

Docs: https://www.php.net/strlen

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/strlen) to actually get a string's length:

```
else if (strlen($username) > 14)
{
  echo 'username too long';
}
else if (strlen($username) < 5)
{
  echo 'username too short';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `strlen()`

```
else if (strlen($username) > 14)
{
  echo 'username too long';
}....
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use strlen($username) instead of $username. It will work fine.